# Not Getting Horizontal Scroll in ListView-GridView - WPF

Tags: wpf, xaml, listview, expander

I am not applying any absolute Width to any layout.
I have ListView inside an expander. The ListView-GridView has many columns (as well as data)- enough to show the horizontal scroll viewer.
But the horizontal scroll doesnt appear.

Following is the XAML :

```
<Window x:Class="TrialCommand.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" >

    <Grid ShowGridLines="True">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition  Width="auto"/>
            <ColumnDefinition  Width="auto"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <Expander  Grid.Column="0" ExpandDirection="Left">
            <Button Width="200" Content="Button1"/>
        </Expander>

        <Grid Grid.Column="1" ShowGridLines="True">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="auto"></RowDefinition>
                <RowDefinition Height="auto"></RowDefinition>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>

            <Button Grid.Row="0" Width="100" Height="20" Content="Button2"  HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>

            <Expander Header="EXP" Grid.Row="1" >
                <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Data}">
                    <ListView.View>
                        <GridView>
                            <GridViewColumn Header="Name " DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Name }"></GridViewColumn>
                            <GridViewColumn Header="Column1" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Column1}"></GridViewColumn>
                            <GridViewColumn Header="Column2" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Column2}"></GridViewColumn>
                            <GridViewColumn Header="Column3" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Column3}"></GridViewColumn>
                            <GridViewColumn Header="Column4" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Column4}"></GridViewColumn>
                            <GridViewColumn Header="Column5" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Column5}"></GridViewColumn>
                            <GridViewColumn Header="Column6" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Column6}"></GridViewColumn>
                            <GridViewColumn Header="Column7" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Column7}"></GridViewColumn>
                            <GridViewColumn Header="Column8" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Column8}"></GridViewColumn>
                            <GridViewColumn Header="Column11" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Column11}"></GridViewColumn>
                            <GridViewColumn Header="Column12" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Column12}"></GridViewColumn>
                            <GridViewColumn Header="Column13" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Column13}"></GridViewColumn>
                            <GridViewColumn Header="Column14" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Column14}"></GridViewColumn>
                            <GridViewColumn Header="Column15" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Column15}"></GridViewColumn>
                            <GridViewColumn Header="Column16" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Column16}"></GridViewColumn>
                            <GridViewColumn Header="Column17" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Column17}"></GridViewColumn>
                            <GridViewColumn Header="Column18" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Column18}"></GridViewColumn>
                            <GridViewColumn Header="Column21" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Column21}"></GridViewColumn>
                            <GridViewColumn Header="Column22" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Column22}"></GridViewColumn>
                            <GridViewColumn Header="Column23" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Column23}"></GridViewColumn>
                            <GridViewColumn Header="Column24" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Column24}"></GridViewColumn>
                            <GridViewColumn Header="Column25" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Column25}"></GridViewColumn>
                            <GridViewColumn Header="Column26" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Column26}"></GridViewColumn>
                            <GridViewColumn Header="Column27" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Column27}"></GridViewColumn>
                            <GridViewColumn Header="Column28" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Column28}"></GridViewColumn>
                        </GridView>
                    </ListView.View>
                </ListView>
            </Expander>
        </Grid>

    </Grid>
</Window>
```

[image]

How can i bring a horizontal scroll view just for Listview ??

Comment: found the solution :
 <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition  Width="auto"/>
            <ColumnDefinition  Width="*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

Answer (score 0):

When container size is set to "Auto", it expands to match the size of it's content, and may grow beyond parent window without showing any scrollbars.

As you mentioned, the solution is to set non-auto size to container. That may be proportional size of Grid column (ColumnDefinition Width="*") or any other way to make container respect parent window measures.